# Resotre-SPSite occurring site collection deletion

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I tried to restore site collection from web application to another web application using SharePoint Shell (Backup-SPSite, and Restore-SPSite) but the site collection in the destination removed without successfully restoring the targeted site collection

no any error appeared only the command create new line and in Logs also no error

SharePoint Version 2019
Site Collection is the main site collection
User running the SharePoint Shell has Farm Admin rights

Answer (score 0):

So when you access the URL of the destination site, any error pops up? If you try to restore the .bak file to another vacant site URL, is the site correctly restored?

You can have a check on the ULS log and event viewer for error messages which may be related to it.

Comment: no error appeared, and when check the ULS no clear error shown related to restore. after checking the version of both environment the source one is higher than destination one

Answer (score 0):

After checking the SharePoint CU version of both source and destination the source higher than destination, after update the issue fixed.